# Setting JFrame Defaults

Tags: java, swing, jframe

There seems to be three lines where I'm wondering why do I need them. To me, it just seems like Java could eliminate this by setting it as the default and letting you turn off.

To me it's assumed that of course I want my label displayed, the exit to actually exit, and my textbox to be visible, otherwise why would I go through all the trouble to build.

Is it possible to remove those lines to have the same code?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class GuiClass extends JFrame {
private JLabel myLabel;

public GuiClass(){
    super("The title bar");
    setLayout (new FlowLayout());

    myLabel = new JLabel ("this is a main text");
    myLabel.setToolTipText ("this is the hover text");
    add(myLabel); //why do i need this?
}
}
```

### GuiClassMain

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GuiClassMain {
    GuiClass myText = new GuiClass();
    myText.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//why do i need this?
    myText.setSize(275,80);
    myText.setVisible(true);//why do i need this?
}
}
```

Comment: There's loads of cases where you may want `myText.setVisible()` to be `false` initially, `true` initially or even change dynamically. Similarly with the other two - there's countless situations where an object needs to be created but is never drawn on the GUI or available to the user.

Comment: Fewer lines doesn't necessarily mean shorter execution times. Those lines are absolutely required for what you want your program to do. If the Java library developers set it as the default, those lines would just be moved to the definitions of `JFrame` instead of in your program. They'll still be there

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about matters easily sorted by consulting the [Java Docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) and trying the code with different values for those methods.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers and comments. This helps me to understand the concepts better. @AndrewThompson yes, I understand it's in the documentation. But it wasn't a question of what or how, but why.  I understand you've been programming for decades, but when you're still in the "hello world" phase, these things are all new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are kind of right. The developers can make them by default, but this will restrict you. All your questions are only valid if there is only one `JFrame` or `JPanel`.

1. There may be more than one `JFrame` or `JPanel` and you may wish to add a `JLabel` to any one of them. If it is done by default, one will be selected and you can not change.
2. Well, you may not always exit the program when you close a `JFrame`. Say, you have two windows: when the master window is closed it exits (or, terminates) the program; but when the slave window is closed it only disposes (`JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`) the slave window, the master window still works on- that means *only* this slave window will be closed, but the program will not be terminated.
3. Again, consider the case when you have created more than one window, but want not to display all of them. All of them won't be visible by default (To me, it is unclear why it is set by default).

I'll give you examples quickly.

Comment: Thanks Paul! This makes sense. I'm new, still in the "hello world" phase, so I was only thinking about one window. But you're right, when I start doing multiple windows, I'll appreciate the current defaults.

Comment: @ldfreeman No worry. I was busy during the whole day, so I could not give you examples (I'll give it soon, hopefully). If you find any of the given answers to be what you are looking for, don't forget to accept it by clicking a tick mark left side of the answer.

Comment: @ldfreeman You may also like to up-vote any answer by clicking on the top face triangle on the left of any answer.

Comment: Hi Paul, I would love to, but I'm new and don't have the rep to vote up yet. But I will once I hit my 15pts. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

> add(myLabel); //why do i need this?

Just because you create a component, the program doesn't know where you want to add the component. You may have two different panels, which is normal for a more complex GUI. It also doesn't know what layout manager is being used and you may need to specify a "constraint" for the layout manager.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information on layout managers that require constraints. The `BorderLayout` would be the easiest to start with.

> ```
> myText.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//why do i need this?
> ```

Try removing the statement and see what happens. Who says you want to always exit the application? Maybe you just want to hide the frame so it can be redisplayed.

> myText.setVisible(true);//why do i need this?

This tells Swing that all components have been added to the frame so know you can display the frame.

Comment: Thanks for the link camickr! This is a really easy tutorial to follow along.

Answer (score 1):

> `myText.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//why do i need this?`

This allows you to change the default close operation of the window, obviously, because you don't want ever window you create to terminate the VM.  The default value is set to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` for safety reasons, because you simply don't want ever window you create to terminate the VM, usually, you only want the main window to do this...

> `myText.setVisible(true);//why do i need this?`

By default all windows are invisible when they are created.  This is done for a number of reasons, the main reason actually tries to solve an issue with how a window's contents is validated.  It also means that when you create a window, you can decide when you actually want it to be displayed, rather then showing, what would be, a blank window...

> `add(myLabel); //why do i need this?`

This is one of this "why not?" questions.  You need to associate a component with a container, otherwise it has no clue about where it should be displayed.

Because you may have many containers, all with different layout requirements, you need to specify which container each component should be associated with.

As you create more complex interfaces, this will make more sense.

Comment: Thanks MP! This was really helpful. In my simple program, it just seems like an extra line, but as my program gets more complex I will be glad the current defaults are set the way they are.